# How do I make an HTML link that doesn't highlight?

Tags: html, css

What I mean by that, is having a link without it highlighting purple/blue when you click it/don't click it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add some CSS styling using CSS pseudo-classes.

Here is an example showing CSS added to the head element in a style tag that changes all links to always be black. However, ideally CSS should be in an external file and for usability you probably want to give some indication that the text is a link.

```html
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
       a:link {color: black;}      /* unvisited link */
       a:visited {color: black;}   /* visited link */
       a:hover {color: black;}     /* mouse over link */
       a:active {color: black;}    /* selected link */
    </style>
</head>
```

*See:*

- [W3 Schools Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp)
- [Smashing Magazine Guide](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/02/13/the-definitive-guide-to-styling-web-links/)
- [Mozilla Documentation :link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:link)
- [Mozilla Documentation :visited](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited)
- [Mozilla Documentation :hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover)
- [Mozilla Documentation :active](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active)

Answer (score 7):

You can use the following css, either in a stylesheet or enclosed in `<style>` tags:

```
a {
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this :-)

```
a:visited {
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! How do I do that with the unvisited link?
I will try "unvisited".
^- That did not work.

Comment: No need to specify `:visited`, this will work fine `a { color: black; }`

Answer (score 1):

If you want it for all your website you can set the style of your body, something like this:

```
body a
{
  color: #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the [CSS Pseudo Classes](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp) to style it.

```
a, a:visited{
     color:#000;
}
```